# Update big text in a CLOB column in Oracle 9

Tags: oracle

I would update this text

```
try1
try2
try3
try4
```

How can i set syntax for do a update in oracle 9?

```
update table set field =  'try1
try2
try3
try4'
where id = 1
```

without text wrap?
I have a text really very big from update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to build the string with anonymous PL/SQL block.

This is just an example that you need to adapt:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> 
SQL> desc lob_table;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 KEY_VALUE                      NUMBER
 C_COL                          CLOB

SQL> 
SQL> declare
  2   v varchar2(10000);
  3  begin
  4   v:='try1' || rpad (' ', 9000, ' ') || 'try2';
  5   dbms_output.put_line('length(v) =  ' || length(v));
  6   update lob_table set c_col = v where key_value=12;
  7  end;
  8  /
length(v) =  9008

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
```

If the above code does not work in Oracle 9, you can try to use DBMS_LOB.

Example:

```
SQL> --
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> --
SQL> DECLARE
  2   value VARCHAR2(10000);
  3   amount binary_integer;
  4   lob_loc CLOB;
  5  BEGIN
  6   value :='try1' || rpad (' ', 9000, ' ') || 'try2';
  7   dbms_output.put_line('length(v) =  ' || length(value));
  8   SELECT c_col INTO lob_loc
  9   FROM lob_table
 10   WHERE key_value = 12 FOR UPDATE;
 11   amount := length(value);
 12   dbms_lob.write (lob_loc, amount, 1, value);
 13   COMMIT;
 14  END;
 15  /
length(v) =  9008

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL>
```

Comment: I have added an example with DBMS_LOB that is available in Oracle 9 (but tested with Oracle 19).